# Does this pointer point to the given object or the address of the given object?

Tags: c++, pointers, terminology

The following is the code.

```
Account savings("Mac, Rita",654321, 123.5);
Account *ptrAccount = &savings;
```

Here, `Account` is a self-defined class, with three fields for data members, i.e., account holder name, account number, account balance. I understand that the first line would create an object and initialize the fields for data members. The second line would create a pointer, with name `ptrAccount`. From my understanding, it would point to `&savings`, which is the address of `savings`. Here, savings is an object of type Account. From the tutorial, it  said something like "the pointer `ptrAccount` is initialized so that it points to the object `savings`." Did I miss something? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Address of your house is 1234 SO street. A pointer to your house would be a sign that says: 1234 SO street. So the pointer holds the address of your house. If I followed that sign, I'd be at your house (dereference the pointer). Another example: If I print the pointer, it'd print your address. If I dereference it and print, it'd print your house.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> From my understanding, it would point to `&savings`, which is the address of `savings`.

Its *value* is `&savings`, the address of `savings`. Hence, it *points to* `savings`.